# Download multiple URLs with curl without repeating the arguments

Tags: bash, curl, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to download multiple URLs using curls:

```
user@PC:~$ curl -LOJ "https://example.com/foo.jpg" "https://example.com/bar.jpg"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   445  100   445    0     0    517      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   518
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
        <head>
                <title>404 - Not Found</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="//wpc.75674.betacdn.net/0075674/www/ec_tpm_bcon.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
user@PC:~$ ls foo.jpg
foo.jpg
user@PC:~$ ls bar.jpg
ls: cannot access 'bar.jpg': No such file or directory
```

But it only applied the arguments (`-LOJ`) to the first URL, so only the first file gets downloaded.

If I repeat the arguments for each URL, this issue no longer occurs and both files get downloaded:

```
user@PC:~$ curl -LOJ "https://example.com/foo.jpg" -LOJ "https://example.com/bar.jpg"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   445  100   445    0     0    481      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   481
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   445  100   445    0     0   1534      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1539
user@PC:~$ ls foo.jpg
foo.jpg
user@PC:~$ ls bar.jpg
bar.jpg
```

So is there a way to have the arguments apply to all the URLs passed to curl without having to repeat it for each URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `-n1`, like

```
{ echo "https://example.com/foo.jpg"; echo "https://example.com/bar.jpg"; } | xargs -n1 curl -LOJ
```

to tell xargs to start a curl for each url, not run a single curl with both urls as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

> So is there a way to have the arguments apply to all the URLs passed to curl without having to repeat it for each URL?

- If you have curl v7.19.0 or higher, there is `--remote-name-all`, to avoid repeating `-O`. `-L` and `-J` only need to be given once.
- If not, you could use `make-url-list | sed 's/^/-O /' | xargs curl -JL`
- If you have `wget`, it has similar options to `-J` and `-O`, in `--content-disposition` and `--trust-server-names`, which apply to all the given URLs.